# Divide a Square to a serval equal squares using Acrgis

Tags: algorithm, vb.net, extents

I'm looking for an algorithm to split a square to a SEVERAL equal squares:
I have only :

- x min , y min
- x max , y max

please see picture (not valid picture only to describe problem):

[image]

**any suggestions please.**

Comment: Your shapes aren't square but rectangles.  More importantly, in your second screen your rectangles aren't equal either.  Can you describe what you are trying to do in greater detail?

Comment: it's only picture that i done with "print" only to describe problem @RussellatISC

Comment: What software/sdk are you looking to use (e.g. esri/arcobjects)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using ArcGIS (based on your question history -- please edit your question to be explicit, though), and you don't actually *need* an algorithm, simply call [Create Fishnet (Data Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000002q000000) from arcpy, ArcObjects, ModelBuilder, etc.

Comment: but do you have any idea how to do it mathematically ??

Comment: What do you mean by "mathematically"?  What are the inputs and what outputs are needed?